# Non-type parameter pack weirdly expanded

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <size_t... s>
struct str
{
    typedef void(&ftype)(decltype(s)...);
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(str<3, 4, 5>::ftype).name() << std::endl;
}
```

The output of this program is `int __cdecl(unsigned int)` when compiled in VS2017, even though from what I understand about the `...` operator, it should expand all arguments. Even strangely, if I modify the code to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <size_t... s>
struct str
{
    template <class Func=void(&)(decltype(s)...)>
    using ftype = Func;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(str<3, 4, 5>::ftype<>).name() << std::endl;
}
```

The result is `void (__cdecl*)(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)`, as expected.

Is this a bug in VC++?

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways one can view your question. The C++ language level, and the QoI level.

On the language level, there is no bug. `typeid(...).name()` returns some implementation defined string. There's no constraints on it. It can even return the same string for all types.

As far as MSVC itself goes, since it can acknowledge the actual number of parameters with your workaround, it's clearly an issue. So yes, one can see an opportunity for improvement here, and this may warrant a report.